# Xcode image operations memory leaking

Tags: ios, xcode, memory, memory-leaks, uiimage

I'm currently having an issue with an iOS project I'm developing. It goes through a procedure where it has to download images from a server, round them and place them on a black background, and finally save them as a file. This loops through over 2.000 URLs of different images and has to process them each. The problem is that there seems to be a huge memory leak somewhere, I just can't figure out how to solve it. The memory warning is triggered four times before the app is terminated.

```
func getRoundedPNGDataFromData(imageData: NSData) -> NSData? {
    let Image: UIImage? = UIImage(data: imageData)!
    let ImageFrame: CGRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, Image!.size.width, Image!.size.height)
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(Image!.size, false, 1.0);
    let CurrentContext: CGContextRef = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(CurrentContext, UIColor.blackColor().CGColor)
    CGContextFillRect(CurrentContext, ImageFrame)
    UIBezierPath(roundedRect: ImageFrame, cornerRadius: 10.0).addClip()
    Image!.drawInRect(ImageFrame)
    let NewImage: UIImage? = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    return UIImagePNGRepresentation(NewImage!)
}

...
var ProgressCounter: Int = 0
    for OID: String in MissingThumbnails {
    let CurrentProgress: CFloat = (CFloat(ProgressCounter) / CFloat(MissingThumbnails.count))
    dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
        progressView?.progress
        progressView?.setProgress(CurrentProgress, animated: true)
    })
    let ThumbURL: NSURL = NSURL(string: "http://\(Host):\(Port)/\(self.WebAPIThumbnailPath)".stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("${OID}", withString: OID, options: [], range: nil).stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("${ThumbnailNumber}", withString: self.padID(5), options: [], range: nil))!
    var ThumbData: NSData? = NSData(contentsOfURL: ThumbURL)
    if (ThumbData != nil) {
        if (ThumbData!.length > 0) {
                var RoundedPNG: NSData? = self.getRoundedPNGDataFromData(ThumbData!)
            if ((RoundedPNG!.writeToFile(FSTools.getDocumentSub("\(self.Structs[Paths.OBJ_THUMBNAILS])/\(OID).png"), atomically: false)) == false) {
                dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {() -> Void in
                    UIApplication.sharedApplication().networkActivityIndicatorVisible = false
                    delegate?.thumbnailCacheCompleted?(false)
                })
            }
            RoundedPNG = nil
            ThumbData = nil
        }
    }
    ProgressCounter++
}
```

Comment: A trick to have code automatically formatted in Xcode it to select the code and enter control-i.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, but it actually ended up being badly formatted because I removed a couple lines from the code before posting it. Might be useful in the future though :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add an autoreleasepool inside the loop to allow the autoreleased memory to be deallocated.

```
for OID: String in MissingThumbnails {
    autoreleasepool {
      /* code */ 
    }
}
```

Autoreleased memory is deallocated when the current autoreleasepool scope is left which generally happens in the runloop. But if the code is tight and the runloop does not run the memory will not be released in a timely manner. Adding an explicit autoreleasepool at each iteration will allowed this temporary autoreleased memory to be reclaimed on each iteration of the loop.

Comment: Thanks, that did it ^^ I remember having tried that, but maybe I just misplaced the autoreleasepool... That saved me from a lot of additional headaches :D